# R - How to get the order of several variables in another variable

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R with several columns of numerical values. I want to create another column showing the order of these columns (doesnt really matter if it's ascending or descending). A rough example:

```
     a b    c  new column
[1,] 1 3 10.0   c,b,a
[2,] 2 1  0.5   a,b,c
[3,] 3 4 11.0   c,b,a
[4,] 4 7  2.0   b,a,c
[5,] 5 8  0.1   b,a,c
```

It seems like there must be some kind of function for this, but I haven't found anything. I would also need some kind of logic to deal with ties/values that are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can loop over the rows of the dataset using `apply` with `MARGIN=1`, get the change the column names order based on the `order` of the row elements and `paste` it together (`toString` is a wrapper for `paste(., collapse=", ")`).

```
d1$newColumn <- apply(d1, 1, function(x) toString(colnames(d1)[order(-x)]))
```

NOTE: In the description, it was mentioned as `data.frame`, but the input dataset looks like `matrix`.  If the dataset is a `matrix` use `cbind` to add another column.  But, it is better to have a `data.frame` as the classes are not the same.

Comment: Thanks! So in case of a tie/same value it will just go in the original order of the columns?

Comment: @user3711502 Yes, in that case, it will be in the original order i.e. `x <- setNames(c(1, 2, 1), letters[1:3]); names(x)[order(-x)]`

Comment: Is there any way to not show column names where there is a blank or NA value? e.g. if a=3, b= NA, c= 5, the result would just be c,a.

Comment: @user3711502  In that case try `apply(d1, 1, function(x) {i <- !is.na(x); toString(colnames(m1)[i][order(-x[i])])})` or `apply(d1, 1, FUN=function(x) toString(names(x)[order(-na.omit(x))]))`

Comment: The firs function works great, but just FYI the second apply function didn't work for me. It just gave me the first x column names in order (where x is the number of non-NA values). e.g. a=1, b=NA, c=10 would give a,c.

Comment: @user3711502 Yes, you are right.  I didn't test it correctly. Thanks for the feedback.